# innerHTML on keypress - cannot get content

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have a function which should grab the innerHTML of a textarea when the enter key is pressed.

The function seems to work with the key press, however the following line returns nothing:

```
var currentHTML = document.getElementById("postcontent").innerHTML;
```

I can't work out what's wrong with the line as it remains empty.

I've created a JS fiddle. Type something in the box and press enter, it should give you some console messages. You'll see that `currentHTML` remains empty when it should be grabbing the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/w4L7c2qh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of innerHTML for textarea.

Updated you demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4L7c2qh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Inner HTML is used to get the content from an [HTML elements](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200508/html_tags_vs_elements_vs_attributes/).

> An element in HTML represents some kind of structure or semantics and
>   generally consists of a start tag, content, and an end tag.

**For Eq;**

```
<div>
    This content can be retrieved using innerHTML.
</div>
```

If you need the content inside the textarea then you can use the `.value` property of javascript,  which will get you the text inside the [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

```
document.getElementById("postcontent").value
```

**Or Else**

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com)

> $("#postcontent").val();